# ReactJS, socket.io client connecting twice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, socket.io

**React version: 17.0.2**

**Socket.IO version: 4.2.0**

I have server working with `ExpressJS`, but I don't understand why is react client side, connecting to server twice with my custom hook.

This is my `SocketContext.tsx`

```
import {createContext} from "react";
import {useSocket} from "../../hooks/socket/useSocket";

let initState = {};

export const SocketContext = createContext(initState);

const SocketProvider = ({children}: any) => {
    const socketHost = process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_DOMAIN || "http://localhost:8000";
    const {socket} = useSocket(socketHost);
    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{socket}}>
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default SocketProvider;
```

`useSocket.ts`

```
import {io} from "socket.io-client";
import {useMemo} from "react";

export const useSocket = (serverPath: string) => {

    const socket = useMemo(() => io(serverPath, {transports: ["websocket"]}), [serverPath]);

    return {
        socket
    };
};
```

And my `App.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import SocketProvider from "./Components/Context/SocketContext";

function App() {

    return (
        <SocketProvider>
            <h3>Hey THERE</h3>

        </SocketProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

If I use hook `useEffect` on `App.tsx`, with a empty array as dependecy it only connect one time, but when I move it to my hook, it is connecting twice.

#### NOT CURRENT STATE, SOME EXAMPLE OF WHAT I TRIED

Edited `App.tsx` with `useEffect`:

```
import React from "react";
import SocketProvider from "./Components/Context/SocketContext";

const connectIo = () => {
    return io("http://localhost:8000", {transports: ["websocket"]});
};

function App() {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState<any>();

    useEffect(() => {
        setSocket(connectIo());
    }, []);

//using SocketCtext, this doesn't call useSocket.
    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={{socket}}>
            <h3>Hey THERE</h3>

        </SocketContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Probably I'm missunderstanding `useMemo` hook, but how can I handle it? I want to move it to a customHook and not using `useEffect`.

> ¿Why not `useEffect`?

Because I want to show when is online or not, using `socket.on("connect", () => setOnline(true))` (socket as dependency) and I get this error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')`.

```
//useSocket.tsx
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState<any>();
    // const socket = useMemo(() => io(serverPath, {transports: ["websocket"]}), [serverPath]);
    const [online, setOnline] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSocket(connectIo());
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("connect", () => {
            setOnline(true);
        });

    }, [socket]);
```

Comment: A possible culprit could be this line: `const socketHost = process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_DOMAIN || "http://localhost:8000";`. Try declaring your `socketHost` variable outside of the component, because for every render of `SocketProvider`, that variable will have a new reference. The new reference will cause `useMemo` inside of `useSocket` to be triggered, so the memoization is useless.

Comment: Another possible solution, and even better from the architectural point of view, would be to put this line `const socketHost = process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_DOMAIN || "http://localhost:8000";` inside of the `useMemo` callback of your `useSocket` hook. `useMemo` wouldn't have any dependencies that way

Comment: I also though it! and removed `process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_DOMAIN` and writed `const socketHost = "http://localhost:8000";`. Now  I edited `useMemo` from my `useSocket` with a empty array. But same result with both edits, it connect twice :/

Comment: Also anther thing is that you're actually connecting once in your `App` component, inside of `useEffect`: `setSocket(connectIo());`. `connectionIo()` is establishing a connection. And then you're connecting again inside of `SocketProvider` > `useSocket` hook > `useMemo` hook. That's why it's connecting twice

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're putting the `socket` inside of your state? The `socket` isn't something that's going to change, so if you don't have a concrete reason why you're putting it inside of your state and even inside of `React context` then I would advise not to do it. If you want to make it reusable, you could simply extract all of the needed methods to a file, and use it from there

Comment: No, no. When I use `useEffect` with `connectIo` on my `App.tsx` file I use `SocketContext` not `SocketProvider`, `SocketContext` doesn't call useSocket, so It connect once.

Comment: I know that React in dev mode purposefully renders each component twice to let you catch unintended side effects. It's possible your hook implementation is incorrect and connecting on each render. You can try building a production bundle and seeing if it only connects once https://andreasheissenberger.medium.com/react-components-render-twice-any-way-to-fix-this-91cf23961625

Comment: @teddybeard you are right! I tried a build and it connect once! hahaha! After reading the post, I removed `</React.StrictMode>` from my `index` and on my backend, one client is connected, didn't know about this! Thanks!

Comment: Although I don't understand why is it rendering twice. I tried writing a console.log inside my `useMemo` and on browser console is writed one time (using React.StrictMode), and a console.log outside `useMemo` but inside `useSocket` and this is writed twice, I thought I was doing a wrong implementation of my hook. Thanks again